# Force URL titles to auto increment and be unqiue

Tags: ee3

Since using EE 3, I've noticed ExpressionEngine doesn't automatically make the url_titles unique - instead giving an error message and telling the user. Is there any way to bring back the functionality of EE 2 where a number was added to make it unique automatically?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You could try Willow's Smart URL at the ExpressionEngine addon page. It works well, although only up to 10 repetitions I think.